# What's the spectrum of this element

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading that

$$ x = {1 \over 2}\left ( \begin{array}{cc}3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{array}\right )$$

is not positive since it has a negative eigenvalue.

I think that $x$ is positive because it is self-adjoint and the only two $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ for which $x - \lambda I$ is not invertible are $-3/2$ and $-1/2$ hence $\sigma (x) = \{-3/2, -1/2\}$. What am I missing?

**Edit** The spectrum is defined as follows:

$$ \sigma (x) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid x - \lambda I \text{ is not invertible }\}$$

I made a sign error in my previous calculation. If $\lambda = -1/2$ then the first row of $x -\lambda I$ becomes $(2,2)$ so in this case $x - \lambda I$ is not invertible therefore $-1/2 \in \sigma (x)$.  Similarly for $-3/2$ and the second row.

**Second edit** Now that I corrected the sign error I no longer believe that the spectrum is non-negative. So my question boils down to:

> I have shown that $ \{-3/2, -1/2\} \subseteq \sigma (x)$. Does $\sigma (x)$ contain any other values?

Comment: Your calculation of $\lambda$ is wrong, should be $1\pm\frac12\sqrt5$.

Comment: @David I don't see it. I now included a definition of the spectrum. Actually, I made a mistake and now I think that the spectrum of $x$ is something else, I will edit again to include my thoughts.

Comment: With $\lambda=-\frac12$ you get$$x-\lambda I=\frac12\pmatrix{4&2\cr2&2\cr}$$which is invertible.  Moreover, you say "the first row is... so... $x-\lambda I$ is not invertible" - there is no way you can tell a matrix is not invertible by looking at a single row, unless it's the zero row.

Comment: @David Thank you, I made a mistake in my calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the product of the eigenvalues is 
$\det(x) = -\frac 14$.  Clearly, one of them is negative.

The spectrum consists of the roots of the characteristic polynomial
$$
x^2 - 2x - \frac 14
$$
given by
$$
x = 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}
$$

Comment: Why are you mentioning eigenvalues? I'm trying to calculate the spectrum.

Comment: The spectrum and eigenvalues coincide for finite rank (and compact) operators

Comment: But in my question I proved that both spectral values are negative. How can the determinant be negative?

Comment: Neither of the values you gave are in the spectrum.  How did you decide that $x - \lambda I$ was not invertible?

Comment: By making a mistake in my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method: the matrix has determinant $-\frac14$.  The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues so one of them must be negative and the other positive.

Comment: Why are you mentioning eigenvalues? I am trying to determine the spectrum.

Comment: As you stated in your question, you are looking for values of $\lambda$ such that $x-\lambda I$ is not invertible.  This is true iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $x$.